# Не выполняется отправка ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

Такая форма:

```html
<form id="visa-form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mail.php'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_fullname" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Пол</label>
            <select name="user_gender" class="form-control">
                <option value="Мужской">Мужской</option>
                <option value="Женский">Женский</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Номер телефона</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" class="form-control" pattern="\d*" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Эл. почта</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Место работы</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_workplace" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить фото</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить скан паспорта</label>
            <input type="file" name="passport_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <input id="send-visa-form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

И такой запрос:

```js
    let visaFormSerialize = $("#visa-form").serialize();
    function sendAjaxForm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: visaFormSerialize,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("success handler");
                console.log(typeof response);
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) { // выполняется эта функция, запрос возвращает ошибку
                console.log("error handler");
                console.log(request.responseText); // output: "<h1> PAGE NOT FOUND: 404"
                console.log(request.statusText); // output: "Not Found"
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    $("#send-visa-form").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm();
        return false;
    });
```

Файл `mail.php` лежим в папке со скриптом, тем не менее выводится ошибка "PAGE NOT FOUND: 404". Не могу понять в чем ошибка. 
Я не понимаю почему выдается ошибка 404, какой именно файл он не может найти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не понял в чем была проблема, но решил все костылем. В файле `index.php` декларировал переменную 
 `const path = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/mail.php'?>";`
и использовал эту переменную в файле скрипта `url: path`.

*P.S* Таки думаю что это из за того что я пользовался `WordPress` и неправильно указал путь к файлу, хоть и подключал файл скрипта в `functions.php`

Answer (score 1):

Файл должен быть не в папке со скриптом, а в папке со страницей или

```
url: "js/mail.php",
```

Comment: я переместил файл `mail.php` в папку со страницей, а скрипт остался в папке `js`. Пути файлов такие: js скрипт: `js/main.js` и php скрипт: `template-parts/mail.php`, папки `js` и `template-parts` в одной папке. И теперь php скрипт относительно js скрипта лежим так `../template-parts/mail.php`. Ну кароче переместить файл не сработало (

Comment: нужно указывать путь не относительно яваскрипта, а относительно страницы где он выполняется